# configuring http access logs in wso2am

Tags: wso2-api-manager

it is written in the documentation of wso2am https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.1.0/administer/logging-and-monitoring/logging/setting-up-logging-per-api/ that wso2am logs each api call in 4 level (request-in, request-out, response-in and response-out). i need to log just in one level because of performance reason. any idea how to configure it to log just in one level?

Comment: Which API Manager version are you using in your environment? The mentioned feature is available via the updated API Manager. You can look at the approach mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70285932/10269117)

Comment: i'm using the version 4. but there was no documentation on the subject in version 4 so that i send a link from version 3.1

Comment: This feature was introduced as an update to APIM 3.1.0, and it is not available in 4.0.0 out-of-the-box. Since you will need to log only one way of the request, you will have to develop a custom mediation sequence or a mediator to achieve your requirement.